# Checking for duplicates in 2 columns before insert involving NULL, SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, duplicates

Currently I have a table1 with PrimaryKey, column1 and column2.
My goal is, before inserting the data into the table to check if column1 + column2 is unique.

Example:
Current data in the table

```
**Primary key           column1           column2**
     1                    1               banana
     2                   NULL              NULL
     3                    2                NULL
     4                    1                NULL
```

Should successfully insert the below data:

```
**Primary key           column1           column2**
       5                   1               apple
       6                   3               banana
       7                   4                NULL
```

Should fail to insert the below data:

```
**Primary key           column1           column2**
       8                   1               banana
       9                   2                NULL
```

I would make the 2 fileds unique but I cant because of the NULL values which I cant fill with data right now.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnnPr.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the table as:

```
create table t (
  a int primary key not null,
  b int,
  c varchar(10),
  constraint uq1 unique (b, c)
);

insert into t (a, b, c) values (1, 1, 'banana');
insert into t (a, b, c) values (2, null, null);
insert into t (a, b, c) values (3, 2, null);
insert into t (a, b, c) values (4, 1, null);
insert into t (a, b, c) values (5, 1, 'apple');
insert into t (a, b, c) values (6, 3, 'banana');
insert into t (a, b, c) values (7, 4, null);
insert into t (a, b, c) values (8, 1, 'banana'); -- fails
insert into t (a, b, c) values (9, 2, null); -- fails
```

See running example at [SQL<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=59849857f7fcb77a272164c3f9e48c0c).

**IMPORTANT NOTE**: The behavior you see here in SQL Server deviates from the SQL Standard -- I would even say it's wrong. SQL Server considers `NULL` as a bona fide distinct value, but it shouldn't; in SQL `null` means "an existing but missing value, and not the absence of value". By comparison all other databases (I know of) consider `NULL` as a non-value, a missing value, that cannot be compared to another `NULL`. Because of this abnormality, this solution only works in SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks, this seems like the solution Im looking for. However, I have quite low experience with SQL Server, so could you please explain how do I add the constraint to my existing table and my 2 fields?
Thanks

Comment: EDIT:
I tried next: 
`ALTER TABLE t
ADD CONSTRAINT b_c UNIQUE (b,c);`

However, I get the next error: 
Msg 1505, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement terminated because a duplicate key was found for the object name 'dbo.t' and the index name 'b_c'. The duplicate key value is (<NULL>, <NULL>).
Yes, I will have data with b = NULL and c = NULL

Comment: @AnAcount Well... that's a side effect of this SQL Server bug with nulls. There's one workaround for it, however. Instead of creating a "unique constraint", you can create a "partial unique index". Try: `create unique index ix1 on t (b, c) where b is not null and c is not null`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `EXCEPT` operator:

```
INSERT INTO table1  (column1,column2) 
SELECT 1, NULL

EXCEPT

SELECT column1,column2
FROM table1 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create UNIQUE CONSTRAINT on that table.

```
ALTER TABLE TableName 
ADD CONSTRAINT UNIQUE (column1, column2);
```

Comment: This doesn't address the question. The OP noted they can't make the fields unique because they might contain null values, and is explicitly looking for a way to identify that they're unique _prior_ to inserting data.